# Handshake exception in java webservice client

Tags: web-services, ssl, cxf, sslhandshakeexception

i am trying to implement a webclient for a secure https connection. I imported the server certificates and added it to java keystore. but when i try to run the client i got the following exceptions:--

```
Oct 18, 2013 3:25:25 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging WARNING: Interceptor for 

{http://tempuri.org/}Service#{http://tempuri.org/}GetUserInformation has thrown exception, 
unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    at $Proxy29.getUserInformation(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.tempuri.ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.main(ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking 
myurl/**/**/asmx: The https URL hostname does not 
match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure 
server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) 
on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is 
correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS 
configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1241)   at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1295)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
    at $Proxy29.getUserInformation(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.tempuri.ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.main(ServiceSoap_ServiceSoap_Client.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking 
myurl/**/**/asmx: The https URL hostname does not 

match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure 

server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set 

the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) 
on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is 
correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS 
configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1241)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at 
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)    at 
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1295)
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Everything seems to be specified in exception message: `The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) 
on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is 
correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS 
configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true`. Did you check CN in the certificate? Or maybe you don't know how to set configuration property?

Comment: @DawidPytel :  yes i did check the cn in certificate. but i don't know how to set the CXF client's TLS configuration property. can you help me out with that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the type of CXF client you have to options. If you have Spring-based client configuration you have to add attribute to your `http:conduit` configuration:

```
<http:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
       <!-- other tls configuration parameters, like trustManagers -->
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

`name` has to match namespace and port name from your WSDL.

If you create your client programmaticaly then use the following code:

```
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
// other TLS/SSL configuration like setting up TrustManagers
tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```

where `port` is actual client proxy that you call.

Both options can be found working in [CXF example that I modified here](https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-handshake-exception-in-java-webservice-client)

BTW. There is a real threat in using this property on production environment, so please consider issuing new certificate with correct CN for production server instead of depending on this hack.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. This worked for me.

HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();

TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters(); // other TLS/SSL configuration like setting up TrustManagers tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true); httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);